# Partial fractions expansion problem $\frac{x^3-1}{4x^3-x}$

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions, rational-functions

I want to calculate integral of the fraction, but first how to find the partial fraction expansion of $\frac{x^3-1}{4x^3-x}$. How to expand denominator? I am a bit lost here.

Comment: $4x^3-x = x(4x^2-1) = x ((2x)^2-1^2) = \dots$

Comment: First you need to long divide, then you can factorize the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the numerator by denominator first..

$$x^3-1=\frac 1 4 (4x^3-x)-\frac 1 4 (x-4)\tag{division algorithm}$$

$$\frac{x^3-1}{4x^3-x}=\frac 1 4 \frac{4x^3-x}{4x^3-x}-\frac 1 4\frac{x-4}{4x^3-x} $$

$$\frac{x^3-1}{4x^3-x}=\frac 1 4 -\frac 1 4\frac{x-4}{4x^3-x} $$
$$\int\frac{x^3-1}{4x^3-x}dx=\int\frac 1 4 dx-\frac 1 4\int\frac{x-4}{4x^3-x} dx$$

after this easy know...!!!! using partial fraction method, we will have

$$\dfrac{x-4}{4x^3-x}=\frac{x-4}{x(2x-1)(2x+1)}=\frac A{x}+\frac B{2x-1}+\frac C {2x+1} $$

Find $A,B,C$ then solve then...

Comment: no big deal, but you forgot an $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: but where?? I did correctly know??@abel

Comment: $\displaystyle x^3-1=\frac 1 4 (4x^3-x)-1\frac 1 4 x$ looks unlikely, for example $x=0$ gives $-1=0$

Comment: you need $\frac{x^3 - 1}{4x^3 - 1} = \frac 14 +\frac 14\left(\frac {x-4}{x(2x-1)(2x+1)}\right)$. there is no cancellation of $x$. you made a mistake at the first line. it should read $x^3 - 1 = \frac14 (4x^3 - x) + \frac 14(x - 4)$

Comment: thank you..for the note.. i maid the correction..@abel

Comment: you are still missing a factor $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: i think it should be $ + \frac{1}{4} (x-4) $ in the first line

Answer (score 0):

$4x^3- x = x(2x+1)(2x-1).$ So write out the denominator like that and see if you can take it from there?

Comment: In partial fractions you need the denominator to have higher degree than the numerator, so need to remove the $\frac 14$ quotient first.